# Scraping Javascript-rendered page that requires login using Python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

My issue is that I can't scrape a website that uses login when it renders the page using Javascript.

I can easily log in using this code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

payload ={
    "username":"username",
    "password":"password"
}
session_requests = requests.session()
result = session_requests.get(login_url)
tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
result = session_requests.post(
    login_url,
    data = payload,
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)
```

Then I can get some values using this code:

```
result = session_requests.get(agent_url, headers = dict(referer = agent_url ))
tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
needed_info = tree.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-6']/div[@class='table-responsive']/table/tbody/tr[22]/td[2]")[0].text
```

However, not everything is rendered.

I've also tried to use dryscrape, however, it does not work on Windows.
Selenium is just too heavy for my needs and I'm having issues installing Spynner (probably because it does not support Python 3.6?)

What would you recommend?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "not everything is rendered"

Comment: Either dig into the page and then directly fetch the sources it loads via JS, or use a headless browser …

Comment: Thank you for your answers. However, I just went and did it with selenium and chrome.

Comment: You probably don't even have to mess with html if it renders on the fly.  There should be raw data you're looking for (most likely in json format). Have you tried to check what http requests come from the website? Or maybe the response has inline `<script>` tags in it?

Answer (score 0):

I just went and did it using selenium. Everything else was just too much of a hassle for this little project.